# Changes in AWK on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, text-processing, awk

I am working with some huge astronomical databases and I just realized that awk is not working as expected. I'm downloading and cutting some .gz files, but awk restrictions are weird, let me share a line from my script:

```
wget -c http://cdn.gea.esac.esa.int/Gaia/gedr3/gaia_source/GaiaSource_000000-003111.csv.gz && zcat GaiaSource_000000-003111.csv.gz |
  awk -F, '$70<=10 && $70!=""' > GaiaCatalog_000000-003111.csv &&
  rm GaiaSource_000000-003111.csv.gz
```

The command line above should download one file of the database, then read the downloaded file with zcat and restrict the lines where the value of column #70 is lower than 10 (and also not null), saving the result in the GaiaCatalog*.csv file. Finally, the command to remove the .gz file.

I verified that these commands are working fine on my home PC (ubuntu 18.04), but they are resulting in empty files on ubuntu 20.04 (when I use a new computer with better storage capacity at my university).

So, what is different with AWK in Ubuntu 20.04? or
Could someone help me by pointing what is wrong with my script?

PS: I noticed that the AWK has been updated from 1.3.3 (18.04) to 1.3.4 (20.04).

Comment: What is your locale? I believe that mawk's handling of the locale-dependent decimal separator has changed - see this recent U&L answer: [awk doesn't recognize field as a number](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/645798/65304) and in particular [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/645782/awk-doesnt-recognize-field-as-a-number#comment1209897_645798)

Comment: You are right, they are different! Thanks, I am going to check this!

Comment: please **[edit]** your question and add information you leave in comments and delete the comments after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I can't find any mention of it in the Changelog, there appears to have been a change in how `mawk` handles the locale's decimal separator.

On 18.04, period is recognized as the separator even when the locale specifies comma:

```
$ mawk -W version
mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan

compiled limits:
max NF             32767
sprintf buffer      2040

$ LC_NUMERIC=fr_BE.UTF-8 locale decimal_point
,

$ echo '99.9' | LC_NUMERIC=fr_BE.UTF-8 mawk '$1 <= 100'
99.9
```

whereas on 20.04 the locale's separator appears to be honored

```
$ mawk -W version
mawk 1.3.4 20200120
Copyright 2008-2019,2020, Thomas E. Dickey
Copyright 1991-1996,2014, Michael D. Brennan

random-funcs:       srandom/random
regex-funcs:        internal
compiled limits:
sprintf buffer      8192
maximum-integer     2147483647

$ LC_NUMERIC=fr_BE.UTF-8 locale decimal_point
,

$ echo '99.9' | LC_NUMERIC=fr_BE.UTF-8 mawk '$1 <= 100'
```

produces no output (because `99.9` is being parsed as a string, and the comparison is lexical).

Your two options seem to be:

1. set the `LC_NUMERIC` appropriately ex.

   ```
   LC_NUMERIC=C awk ....
   ```
2. switch to GNU awk, whose default behavior is to ignore `LC_NUMERIC` unless invoked with `--use-lc-numeric`

See also:

- [awk doesn't recognize field as a number](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/645798/65304)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I tried you solution and it works. However, I also changed the system locale (from Brazil to US, using the graphical interface) and awk is working as I expected too. Once again, thank you for your reply and helpful comments on this.